# Question about URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, cfc

http://localhost/Extranet/mvc/indications.cfc/indication

This is an MVC URL that we use internally. What is the .cfc extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that .cfc is an extension for ColdFusion.

This previously asked question might provide some insight:

[ColdFusion & MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384625/must-one-use-an-mvc-framew-to-produce-clean-urls)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

.cfc is the file extension belonging to a ColdFusion Component.  /indication refers to the name of a method of this component, called indication.

Answer (score 1):

A file with the CFC file extension is a Cold Fusion file.

the file with CFC extension is a web file(.P12, .SVR, .WEBLOC) indeed, commonly known as an Adobe Cold Fusion component file, associated with 'Cold Fusion' by Adobe Systems Incorporated.

Adobe ColdFusion application server and software enables developers to rapidly build, deploy, and maintain robust web applications for the enterprise. ColdFusion is a commercial rapid application development platform invented by Jeremy and JJ Allaire in 1995. Originally designed to make it easier to connect simple HTML pages to a database, by version 2 it had become a full platform that included an IDE in addition to a full scripting language.

The easiest way to open a CFC file is to double-click on it and let your PC decide which default application should open the file. If no program opens the CFC file then you probably don't have an application installed that can view and/or edit CFC files.

More info about it :

http://filext.com/file-extension/CFC[link text](http://filext.com/file-extension/CFC)

Answer (score 0):

`.cfc` is the extension of ColdFusion.